# A free subgroup of GL(2,Z)?

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-groups

Is the subgroup of $GL(2,\mathbb Z)$ generated by the matrices 
$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1  \\\
1 & 0 \end{array} \right) \ \ \text{and} \ \
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
2 & 1  \\\
1 & 0 \end{array} \right)
$$
<strike>free</strike> of exponential growth? More generally, how does one find all the relations between two matrices?

I am sure this is well known, so any relevant references will be appreciated.

My motivation comes from dynamical systems where these matrices specify two automorphisms of the 2-torus; I am interested in studying the orbits of their joint action.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I interpret the question "how does one find all the relations between the matrices" as "find a set of defining relations for the group generated by the two matrices".

To do that we need a presentation of $GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. I found one in the paper:

T. Brady, Automatic structures on Aut$F_2)$, *Arch. Math.* 63, 97-102 (1994).

$\langle p,s,u \mid p^2=s^2=(sp)^4=(upsp)^2=(ups)^3=(us)^2=1 \rangle$

where $p= \left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right)$, $s= \left(\begin{array}{cc}-1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)$, $u= \left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right)$.

Denoting your two matrices by

$a= \left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\1&0\end{array}\right)$,
$b= \left(\begin{array}{cc}2&1\\1&0\end{array}\right)$

we have $a=up$, $b=u^2p$.

Putting $H = \langle a,b \rangle$ and using coset enumeration in Magma, it turns out that $H={\rm GL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$. So your two matrices actually generate all of GL$(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

In fact, denoting $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ by $A$ and $B$, we have

$p=aBa$, $u=a^2Ba$, $s=abaBAbabA$.

Using the modified coset enumeration algorithm, we can compute a presentation of $H$, which came out as the not particularly enlightening

$H = \langle a,b \mid (aBa)^2, (AbaBA)^2, aBabABAbAbABAbAbABAbAbAB, (abABabaB)^3 \rangle$.

Comment: Derek, thanks a lot! This is precisely what I need. I didn't expect $H$ to be all of $GL(2,\mathbb Z)$ but in fact it suits me perfectly. 

Answer (score 14):

A subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbf{Z}$) is free iff it's torsion-free; this is a useful trick (and it's not an immediately obvious fact: it's because $SL(2,\mathbf{Z})$ acts on a tree with finite stabilisers). This is a useful trick in situations like this.

However, if your matrices are denoted $a$ and $b$, then random mucking about gives me that $ba^{-2}$ has order 2, so the subgroup you're asking about cannot possibly be free.

EDIT: this was an answer to the original question "is the group free" and goes nowhere towards answering the revised question.

Comment: Kevin, thanks! I have modified my question. 

Comment: OK! I don't understand the modified question, so don't expect any more from me :-) 

Comment: I will perhaps remark that I spotted $ba^{−2}ba^{−2}=1$ and Mark spotted $[a,b]^6=1$, and these look to me like "distinct relations", if that has any meaning...

Comment: Kevin, I guess the meaning is simply that the subgroup of relations (in the $F_2$ that maps onto this group) is not generated by a single element. Probably not too surprising. Also, even though the statement you mention in the first paragraph is interesting, it is not really needed here. I mean you are using the easy direction, that is, that if there is a non-trivial relation then the group is not free.

Comment: @Sandor: yes I know my first para is logically superfluous---it was an attempt to answer the question "any relevant references will be appreciated".

Comment: Kevin, I thought that you'd know that. I didn't mean to imply anything to the contrary. It is indeed a useful trick. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 12):

No, the subgroup is not free. You can check that if $A$ is your first matrix, $B$ is the second matrix, then $[A,B]^6=1$, where $[A,B]=ABA^{-1}B^{-1}$.

**Update 1.**  There is a paper by Klimenko and Kopteva which might be useful: 
All discrete ${\scr{RP}}$ groups whose generators have real traces. 
Internat. J. Algebra Comput. 15 (2005), no. 3, 577–618. 
It might be in the arXiv, I did not check.

**Update 2.**  The subgroup does have exponential growth. The matrices $B^2$ and $A^6$ belong to the Sanov subgroup. This is a free subgroup of $SL(2,Z)$ consisting of matrices of the form $$\left\[\begin{array}{ll} 4k+1 & 2n \\\ 2m & 4l+1\end{array}\right\].$$ Since $A^6$ and $B^2$ do not commute, they generate a free subgroup of rank 2. The definition of Sanov subgroup can be found in the standard group theory book by *Kargapolov and Merzlyakov*, 14.2.1 and the Exercise 14.2.3 (I refer to the third edition).

Comment: Mark---how did you come to this answer? I am sure you know a lot more about this sort of thing than me. I just computed the char polys of $a^mb^n$ for some small values of $m$ and $n$ until I got lucky. I am sure there are far better ways to go about it!

Comment: Mark, thanks! I have modified my question. 

Comment: @Kevin: I looked at the traces too. These are 1 and 2 - too small to generate a free group. I had done some computation with such groups in the past, and I usually look at the commutator and see if it is torsion first. I think that this is how Klimenko and Kopteva ruled out some cases in their paper as well (it might be even that I was the editor handling their paper in IJAC). 

Comment: I see! The elements I was trying could also be used as part of a 2-element generating set for the group: the commutator is somehow "genuinely deeper in" so I can see the logic in your approach.

Comment: Mark, thanks again! I didn't know about the Sanov subgroup. 

Comment: @Nikita: It is in Kargapolov-Merzlyakov. 